# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, illegalargumentexception, servlet-mapping

I have looked as many as solutions I can But none of them solved my problem.

The problem started when I was running eclipse on two work spaces, did not know that will create all these mess to my server. on the first warning I stopped the server from one of the work spaces and was running on the other. However, when it the problem keep happening, it forced me to close one of the work space.

I have tried many many things, I have uninstalled and reinstalled back, then it works for some day and later I get the same problem. I switched from one work space to another works fine for a while and it happens again. I also relieved from the problem for a week when I switch from V.8.0 to v.7.0. And now what ever i did like before there is now way tomcat is running on my pc.

when I start the server from cmd and type localhost8080 on my browser it looks fine, saying I installed tomcat successfully.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name JustFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3299)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: " Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name JustFilter"

Comment: Hi Stefan, I just got fixed it and It is working now, but i am surprised why I have been getting such kind of warning for this. What I have thought was there might be some configuration issues. Does this happen when there is a problem on the DD?

Comment: Yes, it says there is a mapping on a servlet that did not exist: <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>JustFilter</servlet-name><url-pattern>...</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>. Are you using "web fragments" to modularize your application?

Comment: I am not sure with the wording with web fragment. I am using a filter to log a servlet invocation from a client.